# pod creation through kubernete api

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create pod using kubernete API from a code written in java. I went through the documentation available https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#pod-v1-core but did not find it any helpful. I need to understand how the values are received to the respective API's and which fields are mandatory and optional while creation of pods.

Comment: @shubhandi please add some code sample you have so people can guide you through please follow this link to understand how to ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just create one to see ... experiment ... fail and see ... any good api like Kubernetes will error out on any missing mandatory fields ... Use case is wide for pod creation so answer depends on flavor of pod you desire ... I suggest you create a pod manually from hand editing its config , no need to write code at first ... get your pod creation working without writing any code first before even touching java or any programmatic approach

Comment: you can read more on official documentation : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/ also you can check this out https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

Comment: Got the solution. Found it in the Kubernetes API itself

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/client-libraries.md

> [Java (OSGi)](https://bitbucket.org/amdatulabs/amdatu-kubernetes)
>
> [Java (Fabric8, OSGi)](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)